# combination problems with duplicate objects

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

> Find the total number of ways of selecting 5 letters from the word `INDEPENDENT`

$$
\text{Total #}:11\\
N:3\\
D:2\\
E:3\\
\text{Distinct #}:3
$$
I would have easily done this if it were to find the number of words. How do we deal with such problems having identical objects ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are (at least) two ways of interpreting the question. Suppose it was simply "how many ways of picking 1 letter from INDEPENDENT?". Is the answer 11 or 6? In other words, do we just care what is in the collection of five picked letters, or do we also care about where in the word they came from (or even the order in which they were picked)?

I assume the answer to the question above is 6. In other words, we are just interested in how many different sets of 5 letters we can get by taking 5 letter from INDEPENDENT.This is fairly tedious and error-prone. The basic idea is that you look separately at each kind of duplication.

(1) no duplicates, so pick 5 from 6 letters (ENDPIT) total 6;

(2) one pair, so NN,EE or DD plus 3 from the other 5 letters, total $3{5\choose3}=30$

(3) three of a kind, so NNN or EEE and 2 from the other 5 letters, total $2{5\choose2}=20$

(4) two pairs, so two of NN,EE,DD and one other letter. Total $3\times4=12$

(5) full house, so NNNDD,NNNEE,EEEDD,EEENN. Total 4

**Total 72**

What about the other case, where picking the first E is considered different from picking the second E? Well as @aryanbansai points out in a comment below, that is much easier.

Comment: if first e was considered different would not the answer simply be ${11 \choose 5}$

Comment: @aryanbansal Yes. You are right. I have adjusted the answer.

Comment: its 72 actually, you made a mistake in adding.

Comment: @ss1729 :( Many thanks. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: divide it into mutually exclusive cases:

e.g.

1. when they are all different, choose 5 from INDEPT
2. when you have 2 Es, choose 3 from INDPT

and so on